# MySQL query for grouped data in 15 minutes intervals

Tags: mysql, group-by, intervals

I need an result of my tracked payments where I can see how many of each payment options were used in 15 minutes intervals during the last five hours.

My table "payment_options_log" has two columns: payment_option and created_on.
My first approach was to do it like in an another topic described here on stckoverflow:

```
SELECT MAX(created_on) max_timestamp, payment_option, count(payment_option)
FROM   payment_options_log
WHERE ...
GROUP  BY DATE(created_on), HOUR(created_on), MINUTE(created_on) DIV 15, payment_option;
```

The problem is that I don't get the results for grouped timeperiods with even times like 12:00, 12:15, 12:30 etc.

Has anybody an another solution for my problem? The result should look like:

```
time   payment_option   count
12:00  CreditCard       20
12:00  PayPal           25
12:15  CreditCard       21
12:15  PayPal           19
etc.
```

Comment: Question: Where would `12:07` fall?  Would it be classified under `12:00` or under `12:15` ?

Comment: All values UNTIL 12:15 should fall into the 12:15 interval.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.created_on,
       t2.quarterPeriod,
       t1.payment_option,
       t2.payment_count
FROM payment_options_log t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_on)/(15 * 60)) AS quarterPeriod,
           COUNT(*) AS payment_count
    FROM payment_options_log
    GROUP BY ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_on)/(15 * 60))
) t2
    ON ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.created_on)/(15 * 60)) = t2.quarterPeriod
```

This query would treat `12:07` as belonging to the `12:15` bucket, which may not be what you want.  You could replace `ROUND` with either `FLOOR` or `CEIL`, depending on what you expect.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the desired result :(

Comment: @naptoon I neglected to include all the columns you wanted.  To do this, you can join my first attempt back to your original table.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
Select CONCAT(HOUR(created_on),':', LPAD(MINUTE(created_on) DIV 15 * 15, 2, 0), date_format(created_on, '%p')) as Time, payment_option, count(payment_option) 
from 
payment_options_log 
group by Time, payment_option 
order by Time, payment_option
```

Note: It's a good idea your table should contain a PRIMARY index for each row as well.  I made this to work only with the fields you mentioned above.

One caveat here is that this will use every date/time contained in your table.  If you wanted only today's results we would have to further group by date or specify the date in a WHERE clause.